# Copy JSON Object in ng-model of One md-Select to another md-Select using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-material, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'm having a JSON Collection

```
$scope.person = [
    {
        "Id": 1
        "Name": "John"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2
        "Name": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3
        "Name": "Watson"
    },
];
```

Kindly refer my one of the post [Copy JSON Object of One Select to another Select ng-model using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209946/copy-json-object-of-one-select-to-another-select-ng-model-using-angularjs)

> Here I'm using **Angular Material md-select** instead of HTML Select

In **`md-select`**, ng-options not working. So, kindly assist me how to update Select value of first md-select to second md-select

The Complete HTML Source Code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Select using AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

    <div class="md-block">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Person</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selected.person">
                <md-option ng-repeat="key in person | orderBy:Id" value="{{key}}">({{key.Name}})</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="md-block">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Copy Person</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selected.copy_person">
                <md-option ng-repeat="key in person | orderBy:Id" value="{{key}}">({{key.Name}})</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.person = [
            {
                 "Id": 1,
                 "Name": "John"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "Jack"
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "Watson"
            }
        ];

        $scope.selected = {
            person: null,
            copy_person:null
        };

        $scope.$watchCollection('selected.person', function (newData, oldDaata) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(newData);
            if ((obj != undefined) && (obj != null) && (obj.Id != undefined) && (obj.Id != null) && (obj.Id != "0")) {
                var name = obj.Name;
                alert(name);
                $scope.selected.copy_person = obj;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having two Angular Materials md-Select with same JSON Collection. I Selected a Person Watson in the First md-select "Person", then I need to update the Same in the Second md-select "Copy Person". But I Can't able to update.

I bind the JSON Object as a Value in the md-select options instead of Id or Name

Kindly assist me how to update in md-select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning an object just assign the original value.

Currently are you using this approach:

```
$scope.selected.copy_person = JSON.Parse(newData);
```

Just Change the logic to

```
$scope.selected.copy_person = newData;
```

The Complete Version is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Select using AngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

    <div class="md-block">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Person</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selected.person">
                <md-option ng-repeat="key in person | orderBy:Id" value="{{key}}">({{key.Name}})</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="md-block">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Copy Person</label>
            <md-select ng-model="selected.copy_person">
                <md-option ng-repeat="key in person | orderBy:Id" value="{{key}}">({{key.Name}})</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.person = [
            {
                 "Id": 1,
                 "Name": "John"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "Jack"
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "Watson"
            }
        ];

        $scope.selected = {
            person: null,
            copy_person:null
        };

        $scope.$watchCollection('selected.person', function (newData, oldDaata) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(newData);
            if ((obj != undefined) && (obj != null) && (obj.Id != undefined) && (obj.Id != null) && (obj.Id != "0")) {
                var name = obj.Name;
                alert(name);
                $scope.selected.copy_person = newData;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By default, the Value part assigns the JSON Object as a String, as per your on of the post [Bind JSON Object as a Value in AngularJS HTML Select - Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208965/bind-json-object-as-a-value-in-angularjs-html-select-dropdown) . So, just compare the value as a String instead of JSON Object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately md-select does not support ng-options...

And ng-repeat cannot bind with ng-model of the select component.